# Special use of colSums(), na.rm = TRUE only if 1 or fewer are missing

Tags: r, if-statement, sum, na, na.rm

I need to sum some columns in a data.frame with a rule that says, a column is to be summed to `NA` if more than one observation is missing `NA` if only 1 or less missing it is to be summed regardless.

Say I have some data like this,

```
dfn <- data.frame(
a  = c(3, 3, 0, 3),
b  = c(1, NA, 0, NA),
c  = c(0, 3, NA, 1))

dfn
  a  b  c
1 3  1  0
2 3 NA  3
3 0  0 NA
4 3 NA  1
```

and I apply my rule, and sum the columns with less then 2 missing `NA`. So I get something like this.

```
  a  b  c
1 3  1  0
2 3 NA  3
3 0  0 NA
4 3 NA  1
5 9 NA  4
```

I've played around with `colSums(dfn, na.rm = FALSE)` and `colSums(dfn, na.rm = TRUE)`. In my real data there is more then three columns and also more then 4 rows. I imagine I can count the missing some way and use that as a rule?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you can do this with `colSums` alone, but you can add to its result using `ifelse`:

```
colSums(dfn,na.rm=TRUE) + ifelse(colSums(is.na(dfn)) > 1, NA, 0)
 a  b  c 
 9 NA  4
```

Comment: Works like a charm, I wasn't aware of the open `+ ifelse`. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @EricFail In this context `ifelse` produces another vector of the same size as the result from `colSums`. You are just adding 2 vectors together.

Comment: I see, I keep getting impressed by how freely the function in R can be combined. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Nothing wrong with @James' Answer, but here's a slightly cleaner way:

```
colSums(apply(dfn, 2, function(col) replace(col, match(NA, col), 0)))
# a  b  c 
# 9 NA  4
```

`match(NA, col)` returns the index of the first `NA` in col, `replace` replaces it with `0` and returns the new column, and `apply` returns a `matrix` with all of the new columns.